# Using Laravel sanctum for Laravel default authentication returns 419 error code

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I am using Laravel Sanctum for making authentication. I don't have any SPA application and I want to have Laravel Sanctum for having default authentication.
I have followed the documentation but I've got 419 error code.

Comment: I guess because I launch my project on my local computer and it is on 127.0.0.1:8000. maybe I should run it with homestead. no one has any comments?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to logging to system with Cookie Base application you should add CSRF to your application. And you do not have to use Laravel/Sanctum package if you will not separate your application parts with wildcards. Just use sessions instead of it.